# Есть ли в R функция для получения значения функции Лапласа?

Tags: математика, r, статистика, теория-вероятностей

Для решения разного рода статистических задач в учебниках активно используется [таблица Лапласа](http://www.webmath.ru/poleznoe/table_laplasa.php). Как называется функция в R для получения значений в соответствии с этой таблицей?

Comment: @Volk Эти две метки являются синонимами, просто их не объединили. Не надо их заменять вручную, лучше напишите на мете ([meta]) просьбу их объединить. Про синонимизацию и объединение см. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7334/532877

Comment: ок, понял. Хорошо. Я думал их все просто убрать, чтобы не плодить лишние метки. Напишу тогда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вычислить значение ф-ции Лапласа в точке A  можно следующим образом:

```
pnorm(A)-pnorm(-A)
```

Comment: Точно. А обратно: зная значение функции Лапласа, получить точку?

Comment: Собственно, это ведь тоже очевидно, пользуясь все той же симметрией функции: qnorm((1+q)/2).
Спасибо большое!